# Is it possible to attach a file to an object record IMMEDIATELY AFTER using quick action? How?

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment

I need to attach file to a salesforce object record by quick action. I was able to attach file by quick action using visualforce page + apex, BUT I have to use an intermediary page and a button on it. Thus, first you need to use quick action, and then click the button on the intermediary page that opens, because I linked quick action to this page. I do not need to receive confirmation from the user, enter or output any information on this page. Is it possible to remove this page and attach file directly using apex or flow after using quick action? How? Need detail answer.

Intermediary visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" extensions="OppAndProductsReportGenExt">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="PDF Input">
 
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!savePdf}" value="Attach PDF"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageMessages />
  Pdf will be attached to
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.id}"/><br/>
      <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.Name}"/><br/>
      <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.Invoice_number__c}"/><br/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock></apex:form></apex:page>
```

Handler class for the page

```
public with sharing class OppAndProductsReportGenExt {
public OppAndProductsReportGenExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    opportunity tmp=(opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    parentId=tmp.id;
    pdfName=tmp.Invoice_number__c;
}
private ID parentId ;
private String pdfName ;

public PageReference savePdf() {
    
    PageReference pdf = Page.OppAndProductReport3;
    // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',parentId);
    
    // create the new attachment
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    
    // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
    Blob body;
    
    try {
        
        // returns the output of the page as a PDF
        body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        
        // need to pass unit test -- current bug    
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
    }
    
    attach.Body = body;
    // add the user entered name
    attach.Name = pdfName;
    attach.IsPrivate = false;
    // attach the pdf to the account
    attach.ParentId = parentId;
    insert attach;
    
    // send the user to the account to view results
    return new PageReference('/'+parentId);
    
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a LWC Headless Quick Action. When user clicks the button, invoke method starts. You can call Apex method inside the invoke method.

Example from Developer Guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class HeadlessSimple extends LightningElement {
  @api invoke() {
    console.log("Hi, I'm an action.");
  }
}
```

And here the component configuration: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_quick_actions

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
     <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
   </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```